# How to order wordpress terms by get_term_meta in a custom template

Tags: wordpress

Im trying the following `$args`

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$gender = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'gender',true);

/*
Options of thge select metabox from get_term_meta called gender are listed below.
$gender == "male"
$gender == "female"
*/

// else show paged
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$per_page = 10;
$offset = ( $page -1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'orderby' => $orderby,  'number' => $per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'exclude'       => array(),

    ////** Here Im trying something but it lists all actors**////
    'meta_key' => $gender,
    'orderby' => 'male',

    'exclude_tree'  => array(),
    'include'       => array(),
    'fields'        => 'all',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'child_of'      => 0,
    'pad_counts'    => false,
    'terms'     =>  $term->slug,
    'cache_domain'  => 'core' );
$taxonomy = 'actors';
$count_actors = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
$total_terms = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );
```

This one is the parent term meta `$gender = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'gender',true);` which has two values male and female

So, I can list all in the custom template but I can't separate by male and female fields

How can I list only the terms with this value? `$gender == "male"`

Comment: Use the `meta_value` parameter. So you'd replace `'orderby' => 'male',` with `'meta_value' => 'male',` See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters for other possibilities or advanced meta query.

Comment: :) worked thankyou verymuch Sally